# Property Setters in Multithreaded C++ Classes

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Our application has several worker classes that perform various computations and functions asynchronously in support of a top level MVC application.

These workers are created via a factory pattern that returns a std::unique_ptr to the instance, which is put on a on separate thread using QThread->moveToThread.

In some cases, the application interacts with these to set state by calling setters that set member variables of the worker classes (e.g. passing a bool to a function setDemoMode(true)).

Is this bad practice?  Are there any potential problem scenarios that we are creating for ourselves?  There are been suggestions from some of our developers that we need to make these all signal / slots or mark variables atomic to be thread safe.  I'm all for doing that refactor, but only if necessary considering we have a sizable and tested code base at this point.

Comment: If multiple threads are hitting the same setters for a non-atomic object hitting non-atomic members, you have a recipe for a race condition. If no single object is hit by more than one single thread at any given time (or as you described it, potentially for its lifetime once moved to a single thread), you should be fine.

Comment: The form of this question is open to answers based on opinion, rather than fact. I suggest improving this with a code example.